# How to change the size of textbox? ( tk.Text() ) [tkinter]

Tags: python, tkinter

```
textbox2 = tk.Text(window)
textbox2.place(x=600,y=500)

...
textbox2.delete('1.0', tk.END)
with open("mydb.txt", "r") as f:
    textbox2.insert(tk.END, f.read())
```

In this textbox2, I inserted my text file and it showed what it was in it.
I want to resize my textbox2 (not text size) because it's partially covered.
What should I do to change the size of textbox?

[image]

Comment: Use `width` (number of characters) and `height` (number of visible lines) options to set the text box size.

Comment: You're using `place` which might also be part of the problem, since it doesn't cause the parent to grow or shrink to fit the text widget. `grid` and `pack` are much better at making widgets fit inside each other.